# Xml serialization fails with NullReferenceException on simple class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I've got the simple class I want to serialize:

```
public class InnerCharacter : Object {

    public double xp;
    public double hp;
}
```

I tired difference approaches, for example:

```
public static void TestSerialize()
{
    InnerCharacter c = new InnerCharacter();
    Serialize(c);
}
static public void Serialize(InnerCharacter details)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InnerCharacter));
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Xml.xml")) {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, details);
    }
}
```

I also tried File stream and other approaches, but they all result in the same exception. Here is how I try to load the code in Unity, on one of my GameObjects:

```
public void Start()
{
    TestSerialize();
}
```

They all fail with the same NullReferenceException:

```
NullReferenceException
System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetterAdapterFrame[Object,String] (System.Reflection.Getter`2 getter, System.Object obj) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:234)
System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:292)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMember.GetValue (System.Object ob)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.GetMemberValue (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMember member, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteElementMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObjectElementElements (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob, System.String element, System.String namesp)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob, System.String element, System.String namesp, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType, Boolean writeWrappingElem)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterInterpreter.WriteRoot (System.Object ob)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize (System.Object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter writer)
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object o, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
```

Comment: Looks to me like the exception is happening deeper in the code then what you're showing here, but have you verified that "new XmlSerializer(typeof(InnerCharacter))" is actually returning a valid value?  Or that "new StreamWriter(@"Xml.xml")" is returning a valid value, or that details has a valid value?

Comment: Some problem inheriting from `Object`?  http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/xml-serialization-error.166061/

Comment: @dbc Could you please create an answer? This helped

Comment: @Dvole - I could, though I don't know exactly it fails, or how to work around it.

Comment: @dbc I just removed the inheritance from Object and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` does not work with objects inheriting from [`UnityEngine.Object`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html).  Source:  [XML Serialization error](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/xml-serialization-error.166061/).  Try removing the inheritance if possible.